# Use a KTable or Kstream with Spring Cloud Stream and use Avro

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, avro, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I want to to make an interactive query to my kafka stream topic.

At the moment i can send avro serialized json objects to my topic and read them again with avro deserializer.
I use for this scenario the normal MessageChannel Binder, this works as intended.

Now i want to use the kafka stream binder and i cant get it to work. Maybe someone can help me out there.

My Configuration:

```
    spring:
      cloud:
        bus:
          enabled: true
        stream:
          schemaRegistryClient.endpoint: http://192.168.99.100:8081
          bindings:
            segments-in:
              destination: segments
              contentType: application/vnd.segments-value.v1+avro
            segments-all:
              destination: segments
              group: segments-all
              consumer:
                headerMode: raw
                useNativeDecoding: true
          kafka:
            binder:
              zkNodes: 192.168.99.100:2181
              brokers: 192.168.99.100:32768
            streams:
              bindings:
                segments-all:
                  consumer:
                    keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                    valueSerde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

Kafka Config Class:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MessageConverter classificationMessageConverter() {
        AvroSchemaMessageConverter converter = new AvroSchemaMessageConverter();
        converter.setSchema(Segment.SCHEMA$);
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Schema Config

```
@Configuration
public class SchemaRegistryConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient(@Value("${spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}") final String endpoint) {
        ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient client = new ConfluentSchemaRegistryClient();
        client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        return client;
    }
}
```

And now my Interface

```
public interface Channels {
    String EVENTS = "segments-in";
    String ALLSEGMENTS = "segments-all";

    @Input(Channels.EVENTS)
    SubscribableChannel events();

    @Input(Channels.ALLSEGMENTS)
    KTable<?, ?> segmentsIn();

}
```

I always get following error(Warn Message), but only when i have the second channel open called segmentsIn().

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-3] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

With the SubscribableChannel (segments-in) everything works fine, what am i doing wrong here? How can i get the channel segments-all to work with with the kafka stream api?

Answer (score 1):

I got the connection working with following configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    bus:
      enabled: true
    stream:
      schemaRegistryClient.endpoint: http://192.168.99.100:8081
      bindings:
        segments-in:
          destination: segments
          contentType: application/vnd.segments-value.v1+avro
        segments-all:
          destination: segments
          group: segments-all
          consumer:
            useNativeDecoding: false
        events-out:
          destination: incidents
          group: events-out
          producer:
            useNativeDecoding: false    
      kafka:
        binder:
          zkNodes: 192.168.99.100:2181
          brokers: 192.168.99.100:32768
        streams:
          binder:
            zkNodes: 192.168.99.100:2181
            brokers: 192.168.99.100:32768
            configuration:
              schema.registry.url: http://192.168.99.100:8081
              default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
              default.value.serde: io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
```

See the added config for kafka streams, but i cannot query anything with my code.

I use following snippet:

```
@StreamListener(Channels.ALLSEGMENTS)
@SendTo(Channels.EVENTS_OUT) 
public KStream<Utf8, Long> process(KStream<String, Segment> input) {
    log.info("Read new information");
    return input
            .filter((key, segment) -> segment.getStart().time > 10)
            .map((key, value) -> new KeyValue<>(value.id, value))
            .groupByKey()
            .count(Materialized.as(STORE_NAME))
            .toStream();
}
```

And this scheduler:

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 30000, initialDelay = 5000)
    public void printProductCounts() {
     if (keyValueStore == null) {
            keyValueStore = queryService.getQueryableStoreType(STORE_NAME,                    QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
        }
        String id = "21523XDEf";
        System.out.println(keyValueStore.approximateNumEntries());
        System.out.println("Product ID: " + id + " Count: " + keyValueStore.get(id));
}
```

Output is always:

```
0   
 Product ID: 21523XDEf Count: null
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? What am i doing wrong?